# Using Java JFrame to draw shapes from the user input

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a Java program to ask a user from the choices and then draws the shape. But when I run my code it shows only a JFrame white screen and did not ask. I have 2 class

```
//main.java

public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        new shapesss();


    }
}



//2nd class shapess.java

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class shapesss extends JFrame{

    shapesss(){

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void shapes (Graphics g){

        String choice;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choices: a-Circle,b-Square");
        choice = sc.next();

        if (choice == "a"){

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.drawOval(150, 150, 100, 100);

            }
        else if (choice == "b"){

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.drawRect(150, 150, 100, 100);
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you have not asked a question.  You might ask something like "Please explain why this code does not ask for user input."  That seems to be the real question, rather than an issue about drawing shapes on the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java class names should start with an upper case character. Any textbook or tutorial I have ever seen follows this standard. Learn by example.
2. Don't use a Scanner for user input when using Swing. Instead use a `JOptionPane`.
3. Don't use "==" for String comparison. Instead use the `equals(...)` method.
4. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method of a `JPanel`.

I suggest you start learning Swing basics by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The tutorial has plenty of demos that will show you how to better structure your classes to follow Swing guidelines.

You can start with sections on:

1. Custom Painting
2. How to Make Dialogs

You can also check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more example of painting multiple instances of a shape.

Answer (score 0):

Your code **never asks** for anything because it **never calls** the method `shapes (Graphics g)`.

Initializing g2d should be outside of (before) the conditional if-else since it usually gets executed anyway.  Avoid duplication in code.

Best not to extend a JFrame unless you really are adding functionality.  Instead, make a field to own a JFrame and use that one.